# Finding Reliable Digits in Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, numerics, linear-algebra, approximation

[(cross-posted on Community)](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/897343)

---

> Example: the linear equation system $Ax=b$ has one approximation $\bar x$ and
>   one exact $x^* \neq 0$ solutions. we also gives: $p>3,   \|x^* - \bar
>  x \| \leq 10^{-20} + \|A\|  \|A^{-1}\| 10^{-p} \|x^*\| $ which $\|A\| 
> \|A^{-1}\|=10^{4}$. The reliable digits of $\bar x$ for solutions of
>   this system of equation is $0$.

How we can find the reliable digits of this equation in Mathematica? any idea?

This is written by J.M and one modification by me makes the code wrong, but I couldn't get the answer, when run it online.

```
hm = HilbertMatrix[4]; 
sol = {1, 1, 1, 1}; 
mat = Round[N[hm], 1.*^4]; 
bv = Round[N[hm.sol], 1.*^4]; 
s = LinearSolve[mat, bv]; 
Norm[sol - s]
```

**Now the code is completed, but I couldn't interpret the result, i.e what is the result $0.6780$  means?**

Comment: You are trying to round values of $x\le 1$ to $\mathbb{O}4$, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: You didn't copy my snippet correctly. Did you not notice the negative signs in the exponent?

Comment: You say this is wrong, I removed "-" !! @J.M.

Comment: @Feyre would you please explain more? I didnt get the point.

Comment: "I removed "-" !!" - yes, that's what's wrong. That's what Feyre was also getting at.

Comment: `hm` produces values between $0\le x\le 1$, if you round this to `1*^4`, it will produce nothing but zeroes.

Comment: @J.M. you means it's just work for $10^-4$ not $10^4$?

Comment: I do some practice, cannot capable to implement it. @Feyre thanks

Comment: I'll just post the correct code then

Comment: See Feyre's comment. That's why I told you to run each line one-by-one instead of running them all together, and without the semicolons.

Comment: You are so expert :) @J.M. please be patience when comes to a beginner. I need lot's tutorial when comes to this friendly site and ask from experts. thanks anyway. I need someone help me in more detail on Mathematica.

Comment: "please be patience when comes to a beginner" - and that's why you don't change things in code given to you unless you know what you're doing. You haven't said why you removed those minus signs.

Comment: I think that this "-" sign is related to $10^-4$. now I get the point. thanks so much, sorry @J.M.

Answer (score 2):

There's a mistake in the code, you are trying to round numbers $x<1$ to $\mathbb{O}(4)$ try this:

```
hm = HilbertMatrix[4];
sol = {1, 1, 1, 1};
mat = Round[N[hm], 1.*^-4];
bv = Round[N[hm.sol], 1.*^-4];
s = LinearSolve[mat, bv];
NumberForm[Norm[sol - s], 5]
```

> 0.6780

As @J.M. has pointed out, it makes no sense for the condition number to be $<1$. `Round[N[hm], n>1]` will always yield an array of zeroes.

This rounds `hm` to four significant digits after the `.`

Comment: ...and that's exactly the code I gave the OP in his (now deleted) previous question. I'm not sure why he thought to remove the negative signs in the exponent... anyway, for reference: ``LinearAlgebra`MatrixConditionNumber[mat]`` gives the result `36250.4`, which is why I chose that particular matrix.

Comment: @MichleJordan lines three and four, a `-` before the 4,

Comment: @MichleJordan I can't show anything on a cloud object I have no permission to access.

Comment: @MichleJordan That's the way the line should be.

Comment: @Mic, again, the condition number cannot be less than $1$; so setting it to $10^{-4}$ doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @MichleJordan I'm not sure I get your question. Do you mean the fact that the length of the solution vector is `0.6780`?

Comment: @MichleJordan Like I said, the solution vector has that as length.

Comment: @MichleJordan If you have specific questions on mathematics you can go to math.stackexchange.com The comments aren't meant for extended discussion like this.

Comment: I dont know why you are not clear for me, description of your answer "0.6780" . please be patient and kind with beginner.